# Vertically aligned toolbar with some standard tool

Tags: autodesk-forge

is it possible to create a vertically aligned toolbar with some custom tools (for example measure tools) and remove them from the standard viewer toolbar?

TIA
Alder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create another toolbar instance and make it vertical:

```js
const toolbar = new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.ToolBar('myCustomToolbar', { alignVertically: true });
viewer.container.appendChild(toolbar.container);
```

See this [gist](https://gist.github.com/petrbroz/f0d0af4166326d5de230aee3d49411c8#file-myextension-js-L20) for more details.

And you can also remove buttons from the standard toolbar using the Viewer API, for example:

```js
viewer.toolbar.getControl('modelTools').removeControl('toolbar-sectionTool');
```

Of course, you have to know the IDs of the controls you want to remove. You can find those by inspecting the toolbar during runtime with commands like `viewer.toolbar._controls` or `viewer.toolbar.getControl('foo')._controls`.

Comment: How can I add a standard button (for example measure tool or pan tool) on the vertical toolbar? Thanks Petr

Comment: I haven't tried that myself, but how about taking the button that you removed from the standard toolbar (as shown in the answer), and add the same button to the vertical toolbar (as shown in the answer)?

Comment: Thanks Petr, it works ;-)